Definition of isolated singularities
The following is the definition of isolated singularity given in Functions of One Complex Variable by John Conway, 2nd edition:

A function $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z=a$ if there exists $r>0$ such that $f$ is defined and analytic in $B(a,r)\setminus\{a\}$ but not in $B(a,r)$.

This "but not in $B(a,r)$" means

$f$ is not defined in the whole $B(a,r)$, or
$f$ is not analytic in $B(a,r)$, or
$f$ is neither defined nor analytic in $B(a,r)$.

Since a function cannot be analytic in $B(a,r)$ without being defined in $B(a,r)$, this really means $f$ is defined in the whole $B(a,r)$, analytic in $B(a,r)\setminus\{a\}$ but not analytic in $B(a,r)$, or $f$ is defined in $B(a,r)\setminus\{a\}$ but not at the point $a$.
My question is this: are there complex-valued functions $f$ such that $f$ is defined in the whole $B(a,r)$, analytic in $B(a,r)\setminus\{a\}$ but not analytic in $B(a,r)$?

Only if you allow $f(a)=\infty$ as a value (i.e., $a$ is a pole).

@TedShifrin So this "but not in $B(a,r)$" means $f$ is not defined at $a$?

Yes. That is correct. Notice also that a removable singularity is one type of isolated singularity.
